# Python - How to handle bad parameters when creating new instance?

Tags: python, validation, error-handling

What's the preferred way to handle bad parameters when creating a new instance of a class?

For example, in a card game I might have a card class that can take Club, Heart, Diamond or Spade as the suit when creating a new instance (as well as the value). Do how do I handle someone passing it 'Kitten' as the suit?

I'm new to Python, but know a bit of Objective-C and Swift, and I think in those languages you could make the suit an enum and the compiler might pick up the incorrect value or you could return nil (Ocj-C) or an optional (swift) from the init of the card class.

I understand you cannot return 'nil' in Python (i.e. not create the instance) so perhaps I should return 'None' for the suit (or whatever member is affected) or even throw an exception? Or should I validate the inputs first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class `__init__` method should raise a `ValueError` if it is given something that is incorrect.  When in doubt, check out the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) -- *Errors should never pass silently*.